# How do I change button text on click in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have to change the text of several buttons to whatever I type into a 'textbox'. When I click the first button, the text from the textbox should become the text of the button.
The HTML code:

```
          <input id="textbox" type="text" size="30" />
          <br/>
          <button id="b1">Button 1</button>
          <br/>
          <button id="b2">Button 2</button>
          <br/>
          <button id="b3">Button 3</button>
          <br/>
          <button id="b4">Button 4</button>
          <br/>
          <button id="b5">Button 5</button>
          <br/>
```

I know how to create alerts in javascript using functions and

```
          document.getElementById("b1").onclick = click;
```

but how do I make the button of the text change? What command can I use inside an if statement instead of alert which would replace the text of the button with the text inside the textbox? I have looked all over but can't find the answer. Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the button text like:

```
if(condition) {
    document.getElementById("b1").innerHTML = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
}
```